# htaccess add-on domain RewriteRule not working on subfolders

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, add-on

I have a hosting account on JustHost, my primary domain Is zdental.co, and I have the add-on domain zinapi.com, I am using the following code to restrict access to my subdomain from the primary domain (zinapi.zdental.co):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^zinapi.zdental.co$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.zinapi.zdental.co$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
```

It works fine when I go to url zinapi.zdental.co (not found page is displayed), but when I go directly to zinapi.zdental.co/temp/ this is not working, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule in the root `.htaccess` of  `zinapi.zdental.co`:

```
RewriteEngine On

SetEnvIf Host ^ suppress-error-charset
ErrorDocument 404 "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'></head><body>No se encontró la página que buscas, intenta ingresando a nuestra página principal</body></html>"

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?zinapi\.zdental\.co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but did not work, you can see here: http://zinapi.zdental.co/temp. I need to show the Error 404.

Comment: Still not working: zinapi.zdental.co/temp. This is generating two errors: not found and 500 (Internal Server Error). The File no found error should be similar to this: www.zdental.co/nf

Comment: Looks like you have an `ErrorDocument` setup which you haven't shown in your question.

Comment: Try edited code now. In one of the .htaccess you have `ErrorDocument 404 ...` line that is causing this 500 error.

Comment: Now the error is this http://zdental.zinapi.co/temp (The page is not available).
I have been found a way to redirect: http://pastebin.com/ZNHRdufA, but I would like to show the error 404 instead of redirecting.

Comment: You need to understand that `R=404` doesn't change the URL in browser.

Comment: I have been found a way to show not found error when I write zinapi.zdental.co (http://pastebin.com/8ub9yqL6), but does not work when I write something like this zinapi.zdental.co/temp

Comment: That rule is wrong. I have already provided you an edited solution which should work for you.

Comment: There can be several reasons for 500 error. You will have to see Apache's error.log for actual reason. Are you getting 500 with my latest edited answer. (It has worked for my in my testing)

Comment: If nothing works for you I would highly suggest reverting to `RewriteRule ^ - [F]` rule I proposed initially.